# Why is there whitespace between my header and div?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

As the title says, there is whitespace between header and div. Image can be seen below.
[image: Whitespace in header]

Here is a codepen link that recreates the issue: https://codepen.io/pongbao/pen/MWGXLEm

Thanks a lot to those who can help!

```
<div id="td-div" class="lg:w-1/6 border-2 border-dark-cyan-600 mr-1 mt-1 relative">
                    <form id="td-form">
                        <h2
                            class="text-sm text-center border-b-2 border-dark-cyan-600 bg-dark-cyan-600 py-1 w-full">
                            Time
                            Deposit
                        </h2>
                        <ul class="text-xs font-roboto-mono">
                            <li class="pl-1 pt-1">TENOR: 3 MONTHS</li>
                            <li class="pl-1">RATE: <span id="td-rate">3.0</span>%</li>
                            <li class="pl-1 my-auto w-full inline-flex"><label for="time-deposit-amount">AMOUNT:
                                </label><input id="time-deposit-amount"
                                    class="ml-1 px-1 min-w-0 max-w-full shrink border-b border-slate-400 text-xs text-right"
                                    name="time-deposit-amount" type="number" min="1" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00"
                                    required><span id="max-td-amount"
                                    class="hover:cursor-pointer text-2xs my-auto px-1">MAX</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <button id="td-button" type="submit"
                            class="block mx-auto my-2 py-1 px-1.5 rounded text-xs bg-dark-cyan-300 hover:bg-dark-cyan-400"><a
                                class="inline-flex">Invest<svg fill="none" stroke="currentColor"
                                    stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
                                    class="w-4 h-3 ml-0.5 mt-0.5" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path d="M5 12h14M12 5l7 7-7 7"></path>
                                </svg></a></button>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
```

Comment: I do not see any space in your CodePen in Firefox or Chrome. Are you sure you are not looking at a cached result?

Comment: As @TylerH mentioned, we don't see any white-space on the `CodePen` snippet you have linked.

Comment: Hmm. This is weird, when I try to use different zoom values, it gets fixed. Can you guys also try this out if it happens to you? If it does, is this a visual bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this problems in chrome on my screen that has it's dpi set to 125% but not on my other screen where the dpi is set to 100%. I don't seen the problem in firefox at all.

This leads me to think it might be a DPI scaling issue in chrome. Any chance you are using a HiDPI screen?

I'm not sure if there is any good solution for this, but maybe a css on the h2 might work: (maybe not the best solution, but don't know a better one)

```
position: relative; 
top: -1px; 
left: -1px; 
width: calc(100% + 2px);
```

Comment: Yes, this is most likely the answer. I also think it's a DPI issue as I also have another screen with 100% DPI and there's no issue. Should I report this to Chrome?

Comment: @Pongbao Don't think it's worth reporting. They already have a bunch of issues to fix so this is (most likely) just going to get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Its problem with `border-2` which is `border-width: 2px;` in class list of `#td-div`. Among others values 2px, 3px, 6px, 7px just leave some space like that . Just change `border-2` to `border-[2.5px]`.

Comment: Or `<div id="td-div" class="lg:w-1/6 border-1 ........">` to remove the whitespace

Comment: Still doesn't work T-T

Comment: in codepen for me it works if you change border-width:2px; to border-width:2.5px;